# Missing french.ldf

Tags: babel, french

I am unable to compile any LaTeX file in French. I always get an error message relating to the babel package.

Apparently in the log file, it says the file `french.ldf` is not found and thus babel returns an error:

> ! Package babel Error: Unknown option `french'. Either you
> misspelled it (babel) or the language definition file french.ldf
> was not found.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to find/create that `.ldf` file. I tried updating babel to no avail. I am working under Mageia 5, apparently using TeX Live 2013.

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live
> 2013/Mageia) (format=pdflatex 2016.11.9)

EDIT : A minimal working example would be

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}

\title{Chapitre 3 : Statistiques}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

But as soon as I use babel, the error occurs.

Comment: What about the option `frenchb`? (It would help if you posted a minimal file that demonstrates the problem. It might be trivial in your case, but it is still usually very helpful for others.)

Comment: But `french` should also work. Perhaps you should update.

Comment: A minimal working example would be any document not using the babel package. I added it to my first post.
Also, any option I use with babel (french, frenchb or francais) returns the same error. I'm guessing I have to update babel, or install the .ldf file, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you find `frenchb.ldf`? I can find it using `kpsewhich frenchb.ldf`. Result: `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.ldf`.

Comment: `kpsewhich frenchb.ldf` does not return anything, not even an error message, which I find strange.

Comment: I don't know if this is common policy or not, but I'm trying to make my question noticed again.
I can't seem to find the file frenchb.ldf (or french.ldf, or francais.ldf), using kpsewhich or find. The file is very probably absent from my system, so my question is: how do I install it?

Comment: Using info from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650303/17868), you can [search for `french.ldf`](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=filename&suite=bullseye&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=french.ldf) and you'll see its in the `texlive-lang-french` package.

Answer (score 1):

Using info from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650303/17868), you can [search for `french.ldf`](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=filename&suite=bullseye&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=french.ldf) and you'll see its in the `texlive-lang-french` package.

Installing that package should solve the problem.