# Which texlive (ubuntu) package contains a given tlmgr package?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, tlmgr, continuous-integration

I'm using a GitHub action https://github.com/DanySK/setup-texlive-action to install TexLive, and it works via ubuntu packages. My problem is that I know what `tlmgr` packages I need, but I'm not sure which ubuntu packages they map to. `tlmgr` as a command can be troublesome because it installs from the latest TeXLive, whereas the ubuntu packages aren't the latest when you're dealing with actions.

Example: I need the libertinus font (I'm guessing it's the `texlive-fonts-extra`?). I'm trying to avoid trial and error in actions.

Is there an easy way to find out which Ubuntu package has a given tlmgr package?

Comment: Even if you find an answer to your question, I would recommend using a gh action that uses 'official' texlive instead of Ubuntu packages, as the Ubuntu ones are usually are not up to date as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools allowing search of apt packages. This online search for example will confirm you need `texlive-fonts-extra`

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libertinus

[image]

Comment: It is useful to add the keyword tex to the search, especially for things that are common like tcolorbox

Answer (score 0):

I find `apt-file find <file>` to be useful in these cases. For libertinus, I get the following:

```
$ apt-file find -l libertinus
context                                   
texlive-fonts-extra
texlive-fonts-extra-doc
texlive-latex-extra-doc
texlive-latex-recommended
texlive-luatex
$
```

If you want a more systematic approach, you might fine the following bash script useful: https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/blob/master/findEquivs/findEquivs

If you run this script, it will produce a text file specific to your Ubuntu version (e.g., binaryEquivalent_21.10.txt) with a list of packages. You shouldn't trust the script's output too much, and it takes a while (maybe an hour?) to run, but perhaps it has some building blocks you can use for your use case.